# How to iterate through dictionary with lists as values

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following dictionary:

```
x = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], 'c':[5,6,7]}
```

I need to convert this into three dictionaries that look like:

```
{'a':1,'b':4,'c':5}
{'a':2,'b':5,'c':6}
{'a':3,'b':7,'c':7}
```

Essentially three dictionaries that have the same keys and values that correspond to the same index in each value.

I can do this iteratively but I was wondering if there was a move concise and efficient way of doing this without having a nested for loop.

Comment: You are well experienced with SO and know how it works. Please post your attempts. We are not a code writing service.

Comment: That depends on what you are looking for, are you looking for list of dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know a key (e.g. `a`) and you know the lists are all the same length..

```
[ dict((k,v[i]) for k,v in x.items()) for i in range(len(x['a'])) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of values for each dictionary, then iterate to get a list of dictionaries:

```
x = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], 'c':[5,6,7]}

myValues = list(zip(*x.values()))

myList = [dict(zip(x.keys(), item)) for item in myValues]

print(myList)

[{'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 5}, {'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 7}]
```